# css parent class

Tags: php, html, css, class

I have a question regarding CSS and how to bequeath background information within an unordered list.

I have a footer in that I would like to show different flags. there I have a footer class

```
 <ul class="flag">
     <li id="de"></li>
  </ul>
```

`.flag` consists of:

```
.footer #legals #list2 .flag{
    width: 20px;
    height: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    background-image:url(../images/flags.png);
}
.footer #legals #list2 .flag #de{   
    background-position: -40px;
}
.footer #legals #list2 .flag #en{
    background-position: -20px;
}
.footer #legals #list2 .flag #en_us{
    background-position: -20px;
}
```

So I thought it would be easier for each flag just to change the entry `background-position`. 
But for some reason this is not working and I dont know why? I also tried to use instead of `li id` `div id` but it is still the same.

If there is someone who could help me out I really would appreciate it.

Comment: I'm no css guru but I think the issue is that the UL has a background, attached with .flag class, the LI's don't. try giving the LI's the class of flag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `background-image` is set on the `<ul>` instead of the `<li>`. If you change that first selector from

```
.footer #legals #list2 .flag
```

to

```
.footer #legals #list2 .flag li
```

then the `<li>` will actually have a `background-image` to `position`.